# What is the SEO impact of pointing a Medium blog to a subdomain on my site?

Tags: seo, blog

I am using the Medium blogging platform to blog, but it is pointed to my site and appears at `blog.example.com`.

Since the content is hosted on Medium and pointed to my subdomain via an A Record / CNAME / etc...

1. Will my domain get credit for backlinks to the blog content?
2. If Medium changes in the future and no longer points to my subdomain, will I lose all of the backlinks I've built up?

Answer (score 3):

1. Will my domain get credit for backlinks to the blog content?

   **Ans:** Yes, your domain will get credit for the subdomain.
2. If Medium changes in the future and no longer points to my
   subdomain, will I lose all of the backlinks I've built up?

**Ans:** Yes, You will lose for all the backlinks. But if you redirect this subdomain for any other page (can be root domain or other page) then you get the all points without losing any backlinks.

Answer (score 1):

I never used Medium. Seems it works like Wordpress. So

> Will my domain get credit for backlinks to the blog content?

Yes. Credit will be given to your domain (blog.example.com)

> If Medium changes in the future and no longer points to my subdomain,
>   will I lose all of the backlinks I've built up?

Very unlikely to happen. Anyway if it happens, they may give opportunity to export your content so you can use it in your sub-domain with some other blog software like Wordpress or something. ( But keeping the same old urls will take some effort, again it is very unlikely to happen )